# Как обработать значения location(latitude,longitude) Python Telegram Bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["geo"])
def geo(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", 
    request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
```

Отправляю боту свою геолокацию,в json формате широта и долгота(latitude,longitude) есть,а если попытаться получить эти данные,то выдает ошибку.

```
 print(message.location.latitude)
 >> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'
```

Если пробовать вывести так,то выдает пустое значение,хотя при просмотре json через /getUpdates значение есть.

```
print(message.location)
>>None
```

Как достать значения location?

```
 "location":{"latitude":xx.xxxxxx,"longitude":yy.yyyyyy}}}]}
```

Comment: Может, как `message['location']['latitude']` попробовать? Так или иначе, не вижу, откуда этот `message` берётся (и что он такое вообще), эта информация наверняка помогла бы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем коде немного неправильно используется библиотека.. каждый хендлер - по сути является разово вызываемой функцией. Пользователь что-то прислал - вызвался соответствующий хендлер. Тоесть логика такая: вы отправляете пользователю сообщение с кнопкой, он оправляет местоположение и оно приходит вам новым сообщением на хендлер который принимает location.
Всё происходит в режиме пулинга, тоесть соединение с телеграмом не поддерживается, всё работает отдельными запросами

Вот непосредственно решение вашей задачи:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

token = ""

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=["geo"])
def geo(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
    button_geo = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить местоположение", request_location=True)
    keyboard.add(button_geo)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Привет! Нажми на кнопку и передай мне свое местоположение", reply_markup=keyboard)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["location"])
def location(message):
    if message.location is not None:
        print(message.location)
        print("latitude: %s; longitude: %s" % (message.location.latitude, message.location.longitude))


bot.polling()
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/13BWvE9m
Код на pastebin

Comment: @дмитрийсомов отредактировал ответ, посмотрите

Comment: Огромное спасибо)